# Linear Optimization Study Material

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, optimization, linear-programming

I've recently enrolled in a linear optimization course, and it's been a while since I've taken linear algebra. I do not yet have access to the book for the course or I would skim it to see what I need to refresh on. Could someone who's taken/taught a linear optimization course point me in the right direction of what to relearn from linear algebra.

Comment: If you could provide us a course outline from your professor, it would be helpful. At the basic, know how to row reduce, how to multiple/add matrices and be fluent with inequalities.

Comment: Unfortunately the professor has not posted a syllabus or the required textbook. I'm looking through my liner algebra book and there are three things I don't recall very well; (1) Subspaces, (2) eigenvalues/eigenvectors, and (3) linear transformations.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of books have the necessary preliminaries built in, but if you know linear algebra at the level of Strang's Linear algebra and its applications, you should be fine. Try checking out Luenberger's Linear and Nonlinear programming and Bertsemas' Linear Optimization. Vanderbei's linear optimization  is another good option.